# Receive data form keyboard using ASP.NET without TextBox

Tags: asp.net, keyboard, usb, port

I have a web application using asp.net. I want the web page to auto listen and receive data from the keyboard (usb port) when client typing. **Note**: not using a control like a TextBox, and not requiring the caret in a TextBox control.

How can I have the web page receive keyboard input without a relevant control like a TextBox?

Thanks.

Comment: can you show us what you've tried? community on SO can help better that way

Comment: a javascript listener would catch a keystroke. Are you trying to catch a particular button, like ENTER?

Comment: Are you planning to show the typed input the user somehow?! If not how is the user going to know whether he/she has typed enough?!

Comment: I want show data in lable.
I thing can use applet(java) request listen keyboard?